# Get multiple fields count from one query in MongoDB?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of events its structure is as follows :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537b3ff288f4ca2f471afcae"),
    "Name" : "PREMISES MAP DELETED",
    "ScreenName" : "AccessPointActivity",
    "Timestamp" : NumberLong("1392113758000"),
    "EventParams" : "null",
    "TracInfo" : {
            "ApplicationId" : "fa41f204bfc711e3b9f9c8cbb8c502c4",
            "DeviceId" : "2_1VafJVPu4yfdbMWO1XGROjK6iQZhq4hAVCQL837W",
            "UserId" : "pawan",
            "SessionId" : "a8UHE16mowNwNGyuLXbW",
            "WiFiAP" : "null",
            "WiFiStrength" : 0,
            "BluetoothID" : "null",
            "BluetoothStrength" : 0,
            "NetworkType" : "null",
            "NetworkSubType" : "null",
            "NetworkCarrier" : "Idea",
            "Age" : 43,
            "Gender" : "Female",
            "OSVersion" : "16",
            "Manufacturer" : "samsung",
            "Resolution" : "600*976",
            "Platform" : "Android",
            "Latitude" : 40.42,
            "Longitude" : -74,
            "City" : "Monmouth County",
            "CityLowerCase" : "monmouth county",
            "Country" : "United States",
            "CountryLowerCase" : "united states",
            "Region" : "New Jersey",
            "RegionLowerCase" : "new jersey",
            "Time_zone" : "null",
            "PinCode" : "07732",
            "Locale" : ", Paradise Trailer Park",
            "Accuracy" : 0,
            "Timestamp" : NumberLong("1392113758000")
    }
}
```

their are many event on different screens.

My expected output is as follows :

```
{
    ApplicationId:"fa41f204bfc711e3b9f9c8cbb8c502c4",
    EventName:"PREMISES MAP DELETED",
    Eventcount:300, 
    ScreenviewCount:20,
    DeviceCount:10, 
    UserCount:3 
}
```

EventCount : It is count of EventName

ScreenviewCount : It is the count of distinct screenName distinct per session

DeviceCount : It is the count of distinct deviceId

UserCount : It is the count of distinct userCount

Their will be multiple event on multiple screens(ScreenName).

Currently i' am using following approach :

1. Using aggregation to get each event name and it count
   eg :

   ```
     {    
       _id:
       {
           ApplicationId:"fa41f204bfc711e3b9f9c8cbb8c502c4",
           EventName:"PREMISES MAP DELETED"    
       }
       EventCount:300
   ```

   }
2. For each event name from above aggregation result I call following queries in while loop until aggregation output has documents:

a) Distinct query using eventName from aggregation output for screenview count(on event collection).

b) Distinct query eventName from aggregation output for device count(on event collection).

c) Distinct query eventName from aggregation output for user count(on event collection).

And the problem is its slow as it has 3 distinct queries on each result of aggregation output.

Is their any way to do it in single aggregation call or something else.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Looks possible. But it is very unclear what you are actually querying on for your totals. I could guess at part of it but I'd really be guessing at "what is a 'screenview'"? It means something to you, but not clear to the rest of us. Best share some code you are currently running in your question so we know what fields are being used for the totals.

Comment: hi!  Neil Lunn i have edited the question, hope so now the picture is clear. Thank you!

Comment: Did you read through the answer? It should be basically what you want. I was generally saying that without your existing code we are "guessing" at the fields you want distinct counts from as your terms do not directly match existing field names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general case here that you seemed to have missed is that to get the "distinct" values of various fields in your document under the "event" totals you can use the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator.

A "set" by definition has all of it's values "unique/distinct", so you just want to hold all those possible values in a "set" for your grouping level and then get the "size" of the array produced, which is exactly what the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator introduced in MongoDB 2.6 does.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ApplicationId": "$TracInfo.ApplicationId",
            "EventName": "$Name",
        },
        "oScreenViewCount": { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "ScreenName": "$ScreenName",
                "SessionId": "$TracInfo.SessionId",
            }
        },
        "oDeviceCount": { "$addToSet": "$TracInfo.DeviceId" },
        "oUserCount": { "$addToSet": "$TracInfo.UserId" },
        "oEventcount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "ApplicationId": "$_id.ApplicationId",
        "EventName": "$_id.EventName",
        "EventCount": "$oEventCount",
        "ScreenViewCount": { "$size": "$oScreenViewCount" },
        "DeviceCount": { "$size": "$oDeviceCount" },
        "UserCount": { "$size": "$oUserCount" }
    }}
])
```

Versions pre MongoDB 2.6 require a little more work, using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count the arrays:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ApplicationId": "$TracInfo.ApplicationId",
            "EventName": "$Name",
        },
        "oScreenviewCount": { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "ScreenName": "$ScreenName",
                "SessionId": "$TracInfo.SessionId",
            }
        },
        "oDeviceCount": { "$addToSet": "$TracInfo.DeviceId" },
        "oUserCount": { "$addToSet": "$TracInfo.UserId" },
        "oEventcount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$oScreeenviewCount" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "oScreenviewCount": { "$sum": 1 },
        "oDeviceCount": { "$first": "$oDeviceCount" },
        "oUserCount": { "$first": "$oUserCount" },
        "oEventcount": { "$first": "$oEventCount" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$oDeviceCount" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "oScreenviewCount": { "$first": "$oScreenViewCount" },
        "oDeviceCount": { "$sum": "$oDeviceCount" },
        "oUserCount": { "$first": "$oUserCount" },
        "oEventcount": { "$first": "$oEventCount" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$oUserCount" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "oScreenviewCount": { "$first": "$oScreenViewCount" },
        "oDeviceCount": { "$first": "$oDeviceCount" },
        "oUserCount": { "$sum": "$oUserCount" },
        "oEventcount": { "$first": "$oEventCount" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "ApplicationId": "$_id.ApplicationId",
        "EventName": "$_id.EventName",
        "EventCount": "$oEventCount",
        "ScreenViewCount": "$oScreenViewCount",
        "DeviceCount": "$oDeviceCount",
        "UserCount": "$oUserCount"
    }}

])
```

The end usage of [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in the second listing and all the general usage of the "o" prefixed names is really just for prettying up the result at the end and making sure the output field order is the same as in your sample result.

As a general disclaimer, your question lacks the information to determine the exact fields or combinations that are used for these totals, but the principles and approach are sound and should be near enough to the same implementation.

So essentially, you are getting the "distinct" values within the "group" by using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) for whatever the field or combination is and then you are determining the "count" of those "sets" by whatever means is available to you.

Much better than issuing many queries and merging results in client code.

Comment: +1 @Neil, learnt a new usage of $addToSet in a composite form (oScreenviewCount)

Comment: @Neil Lunn m getting following error "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO"

Comment: @Niand What does your outuput look like when you omit the final `$project`? It would seem a field is either misnamed or does not exist in a document somewhere.

Comment: @neil lunn $oScreenViewCount was $oScreenviewCount...Its working great thanks!!! a tone saved me from performance loss...and thanks a tone for teaching me $size and $addToSet

Comment: @Niand glad it helped. Don't forget to **accept** your answers. Helps everyone know the response has been closed. And helps everyone who helps you